# Mac OS FTP Directory Listing

Tags: macos, ftp, midnight-commander

I use Mac OS X. `mc` was installed from ports. Mouse is not supported in `mc`. I try to connect to FTP server.

1. <kbd>fn + F9</kbd>.
2. Chose Right, than FTP Link... .
3. In the "Enter machine name (F1 for details)" there is a drop-down list (`[^]`). What is the key to chose `[^]`?

I know that I can use <kbd>Ctrl + \</kbd> to save path. But could you tell me how can I press `[^]` without mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to show the list of previously used servers. This requires that you have set the option *Use Option as Meta key* in Terminal.